# Right index for slow distinct query

Tags: mongodb

I'm using a distict query with filter defined and query is quire slow on database with 73K items. The query looks like this:

```
db.runCommand({ "distinct": "companies", "key": "approver", 
                "query": { "doc_readers": { "$in": [ "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_MODUL_CUST", "ROLE_MODUL_PROJECTS" ] } } })
```

Query stats is here:

```
 "stats" : {
                "n" : 73394,
                "nscanned" : 146788,
                "nscannedObjects" : 73394,
                "timems" : 292,
                "cursor" : "BtreeCursor doc_readers_1"
},
```

It shows that it checks every item to get distinct list of approvers here . Is there a way how to create a better index to speed up things? I have a 3 similar queries on one web page so together they take 1 sec to get data.

**Update 1: I have the following indexes**

Only the first one is beeing used as stats shows ...

```
 {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
                  "doc_readers" : 1
            },
        "name" : "doc_readers_1",
        "ns" : "netnotes.companies",
        "sparse" : false
}, 
{                                                       
        "v" : 1,                                        
        "key" : {                                       
                "doc_readers" : 1,                      
                "approver" : 1                      
        },                                              
        "name" : "doc_readers_1_schvalovatel_1",        
        "ns" : "netnotes.companies"                     
},                                                      
{                                                       
        "v" : 1,                                        
        "key" : {                                       
                "approver" : 1,                     
                "doc_readers" : 1                       
        },                                              
        "name" : "schvalovatel_1_doc_readers_1",        
        "ns" : "netnotes.companies"                     
},
```

Comment: What if you add approver to your index?

Comment: Index info updated above ...

Comment: What happens if you just run a find query over your collection and iterate over the results ? How many entries do you have in your collection with 'doc_readers' of one of the 3 types you're checking ?

Comment: Query finds cca. 100 distinct values from the collection of 73K documents ... more I think about it more I feel its probably not possible to solve and must be redesigned somehow in application

Comment: The problem is not that it is doing a collection scan, it is not, the problem is that you are loading 73K documents into the working set. I need to look into this when I get a chance

Comment: It's not doing a collection scan. It uses the index on `doc_readers` to perform the first query, then scans the results for distinct values of `approver`. It seems like it should be able to use an index on `{ "doc_readers" : 1, "approver" : 1}` to serve the distinct, but it doesn't presently (I tested 2.6.3). I'd suggesting making a [SERVER ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER) for this and see what MongoDB engineering says.